# Passing char pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am learning pointers in C, so I did this to check out the output I should hope when I do something. Here it is:

```
int characters(char temp[])
{
    printf("\nAddress of string by &temp: %p",&temp);
    printf("\nAddress of string by temp: %p",temp);
    printf("\nContent of string: %s",temp);     
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    char s[] = "Prafulla Shahi";
    char *t=s;
    clrscr();
    characters(t);
    printf("\nMain\nAddress of string by &s: %p",&s);
    printf("\nAddress of string by s: %p",s);
    printf("\nContent of string: %s",s);
    printf("\nAddress of pointer by &t: %p",&t);
    printf("\nAddress of pointer by t: %p",t);
    printf("\nContent of pointer: %s",t);
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

The output I get is this:

```
Address of string by &temp: 0x7fff4ab45788
Address of string by temp: 0x7fff4ab457b0
Content of string: Prafulla Shahi    
Main
Address of string by &s: 0x7fff4ab457b0
Address of string by s: 0x7fff4ab457b0
Content of string: Prafulla Shahi
Address of pointer by &t: 0x7fff4ab457a8
Address of pointer by t: 0x7fff4ab457b0
Content of pointer: Prafulla Shahi
```

My question is:
Whys is the address for the temp array show two different values when asked by &temp and temp?

My understanding is, temp is an array variable, but it has its own address (similar behavior to the pointer t. Why does it not behave like the usual variable array s?). The array s[] in main() is an array too, but its address when called by &s and s shows the same value.

Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: Note that you can only accept *one* answer. Choose which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char s[] = "Hello world";
```

`s` is an array object (initialized with a string literal). The address of the array and the address of the first element of the array are the same (only the types are different).

So:

```
(char *) &s == s  /* value of the == expression is 1 */
```

But:

```
char *p = "Hello world";
```

`p` is a pointer object (pointing to a string literal). The address of `p` is the address of the pointer object and this address is different than the value of `p` which is a pointer to the first character of the `"Hello world"` string.

So:

```
(char *) &p == p  /* value of the == expression is 0 */
```

To be complete going back to your example I also have to add that an array parameter in a function declaration is *adjusted* in C to a parameter of a pointer type. So these two function declarations are equivalent:

```
 int characters(char temp[]) { /* ... */ }
```

and

```
 int characters(char *temp) { /* ... */ }
```

which also means that inside `characters` function, we have:

```
(char *) &temp == temp  /* value of the == expression is 0 */
```

because `temp` is a pointer object and not an array object.

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding is, `temp` is an array variable

Unfortunately, **no, it isn't.**

When you pass an array to a function, it decays into a pointer to its first element. As a quite logical consequence, it was decided that when you declare a function argument like an array, it will be interpreted as a pointer. So in function argument declarations, **and only in function argument declarations,** the array notation is **equivalent with the pointer qualifier.** So

```
int characters(char temp[])
```

is the **same** as

```
int characters(char *temp)
```

And a pointer is an object that holds a value (an address) and has an own address too, so of course `temp` is not the same as `&temp`.

Have you declared `temp` outside a function argument as a **real array** (and not a pointer), would your expectation have been met; and then of course `&temp` would have pointed to the same address as the pointer `temp` itself decayed into.

Answer (score 1):

When being passed to a function, an array is decomposed to a pointer (to its first element).  You are allowed to use array notation to make your life easier, but as far as the compiler is concerned temp is a char *, not an actual array.  This is why it is behaving the same as t, rather than s.

Answer (score 1):

`s` is an statically allocated array. Its value and the address of its first element are therefore the same.

Both `t` and `temp` are new pointer variables pointing to `s`. Their value is the address of `s`. But each one of these variables are separately allocated, so each one has its own address.

```
s (address = 0x7fff4ab457b0)
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| P | r | a | f | u | l | l | a |   | S | h | a | h | i |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^
  |  temp (address = 0x7fff4ab45788)
  |  +----------------+
  +--| 0x7fff4ab457b0 |
  |  +----------------+
  |
  |  t (address = 0x7fff4ab457a8)
  |  +----------------+
  +--| 0x7fff4ab457b0 |
     +----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `character(char temp[])` definition function, `temp` is a pointer to `char`. When you pass the name of an array as argument the address of the first element of it is copied to `temp`. check this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm

So when you try to print the value of `temp` it prints the address of the first element of the array. But when you try to print the value of `&temp` you're not printing the address of the array but you're printing the address of the pointer itself.

To print the address with other way you may use this:

```
printf("\nAddress of string by &temp: %u",&temp[0]);
```

Comment: *Note that when printing the addresses we use %p not %u*.